# Trying to understand tkinter grid of rectangles generation

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to understand the following code, it creates a grid of rectangles within a canvas. I have two issues that I would like to understand. Firstly, the grid of rectangles seems to be cut off at the bottom, so how would I achieve a full width/height of canvas one? Secondly, how do I specify the amount of rectangles generated?

```
import tkinter as tk

l = [[0,0,0,0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
n = len(l) * 5
lngt = 400 // n

fen = tk.Tk()
fen.state('zoomed')

can = tk.Canvas(fen)
can.pack(fill='both')

for i in range(n):
    y = i * lngt
    for j in range(n):
        x = j * lngt
        can.create_rectangle(x, y, x+lngt, y+lngt, fill="#444")

fen.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve a full width/height canvas configuring the expand option of `canvas`' geometry manager, `pack`.

```
can.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
```

---

For the code above you can specify the number of rectangles by assigning the variable `n`. Which is the square root of the total number of rectangles. For the code above, it is equal to 20.